# Count words in a file java program

Tags: java

I am writing a simple code to count how many words there are in a txt file with java. It doesn't work cause it has a "noSuchElementException". Can you please help me fix it? Thank you!

```
public class Nr_Fjaleve {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("teksti.txt"));
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("countwords.txt"));
    int count = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String fjala = input.next();
        count++;
    }
    output.print(count);
}

}
```

Comment: what is the element it can't find?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at Nr_Fjaleve.main(Nr_Fjaleve.java:13)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `hasNextLine` but then you are retrieving just `next`.

So simply change your code to:

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String fjala = input.next();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I took a look at your problem and immediately found a solution.
In order to try to be as helpful as possible, I want to give a possible approach (I would personally use) which is more readable and can be used in the Java 8 Lambda Environment.

```
public class Nr_Fjaleve {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("teksti.txt"));
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("countwords.txt"));

        final int count = Stream.of(input).map(i -> {
            try {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                // Your original problem was here as you called the #next method 
                // while iterating over it with the #hasNext method. This will make the counting go wrong.
                while (i.hasNextLine()) {
                    builder.append(i.nextLine());
                }
                return builder;
            } finally {
                i.close();
            }
        }).mapToInt(StringBuilder::length).sum();

        output.print(count);
    }

}
```

Hopefully this was of any help.

Comment: Appending to a builder _losese_ all whitespace chars. Then mapping the concatenation to the length and summing up the (single) value leads to a complete other result. And why use a stream where a simple loop works very well?

Comment: I edited my code to build with the whitespace chars appended as well. I am someone who generally prefers working with Streams due to the flexebility in the possibilities that you have. I can see your direct way of approaching a problem. Thank you for your feedback.